# Insert rows in the datagridview with a dictionary

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, hash-map

I would like to improve the function below **without** calling twice `InserisciRigaNote`.

Before I fill my `dictionary`. When I compare `idNota` with the current database `id` I check if it is equal or not, if different means that the `dictionary` is filled and I can proceed with the insertion of the row in `DataGridView`

I have a query that return this output:

[image: Output MySQL Query]

I have to fill a `DataGridView` in that way

[image: DataGridView with language]

```
string query = ""; // Query MySQL              
using (MySqlDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(query))
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        int idNota = 1;
        var note = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (idNota != Convert.ToInt32(reader["id_nota_lavaggio"]))
            {
                InserisciRigaNote(note, idNota); // Function that insert row in the DataGridView

                idNota = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id_nota_lavaggio"]);
                note.Clear();
            }
            // Create a dictionary made by a language key and a description
            note[reader["id_lingua"].ToString()] = reader["descrizione_nota_lavaggio"].ToString();
        }
        if (note.Count > 0) // If there is something in the dictionary
        {
            InserisciRigaNote(note, idNota);
            note.Clear();
        }

    }
}
```

**N.B.** 
I did not use **Pivot** to make the query because I need it's all completely dynamic

Comment: You can do dynamic pivot queries too.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is really confusing, not in the least because it is partly in Italian.

---

It does seem to me that you've coupled your UI and your back-end, and that's something to avoid. Look into [developing an n-tier application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384570.aspx) so your db related code is in a back-end and all you're exposing to the UI is a collection of some sort with data objects.

And the you can [bind that collection to your DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16695971/648075), which is a much nicer solution instead of inserting one row at a time. Ideally you'd abandon WinForms, instead look into more modern technologies like WPF and [apply MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484.aspx). But if you're stuck with WinForms there are still ways to [apply something like MVP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/595538/648075).

---

That is of course a massive leap from the code you have here, so try refactoring one bit at the time.

- Construct a class that can contain the results of your db-query, and fill a collection, so you can properly bind your data instead of inserting rows.
- Beware of strings like `"id_nota_lavaggio"` and consider defining them as `const` so you can easily update them if necessary.
- Twice you do `Convert.ToInt32(reader["id_nota_lavaggio"])`: instead, do it once and store the result in a variable.
- I don't know about how well Entity Framework works with MySQL, but there are other ORMs available anyway, so when possible consider abandoning writing ADO and instead work with an ORM.
- Comments should tell us why, not what. `// Query MySQL` is superfluous, and something like `// Create a dictionary made by a language key and a description` should be told by the code, not the comments (ditto `// If there is something in the dictionary`).

Answer (score 2):

Use a pivot query to select the data from the database in the correct format. Then you don't need to use a dictionary, but just a regular old `List` which you can bind to.

```
dataGridView.DataSource = myPivotedQueryResults
```